# Setting IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW in unix like serial

Tags: objective-c, unix, serial-port, setting

I neet do implement a two way communication with a device with a flow control is also known as RTS/CTS. I've configured my termios structure in order to have the right flow control, but no way to init the communication.
I've sniffed packets with a windows software and on win there are also other setup before sending the packets:

```
1 000004: I/O Request (DOWN), 23.01.2015 17:30:53.934 +0.0 (1. Device: Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM1))
  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_QUEUE_SIZE: Set queue size
  InSize=4096
  OutSize=4096
2 000006: I/O Request (DOWN), 23.01.2015 17:30:53.934 +0.0 (1. Device: Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM1))
  IOCTL_SERIAL_PURGE: Purge requests
  Purge mask=TXABORT: Read requests, RXABORT: Receive buffer, TXCLEAR: Write requests, RXCLEAR: Write buffer
3 000024: I/O Request (DOWN), 23.01.2015 17:30:53.934 +0.0 (1. Device: Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM1))
  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE: Set baud rate
  Baud Rate=1200
4 000030: I/O Request (DOWN), 23.01.2015 17:30:53.940 +0.0 (1. Device: Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM1))
  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL: Set line control
  WordLength=8
  StopBits=1 stop bit
  Parity=Odd parity
5 000032: I/O Request (DOWN), 23.01.2015 17:30:53.942 +0.0 (1. Device: Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM1))
  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_CHARS: Set special characters
  EofChar=0x0
  ErrorChar=0x0
  BreakChar=0x0
  EventChar=0x0
  XonChar=0x11
  XoffChar=0x13
6 000034: I/O Request (DOWN), 23.01.2015 17:30:53.942 +0.0 (1. Device: Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM1))
  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW: Set handshake information
  ControlHandShake=2147483649
  FlowReplace=0
  XonLimit=2048
  XoffLimit=512
7 000038: I/O Request (DOWN), 23.01.2015 17:30:53.946 +0.0 (1. Device: Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM1))
  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS: Set timeouts
  ReadIntervalTimeout=0
  ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=20
  ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=90
  WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10
  WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=50
  000053: I/O Request (UP), 23.01.2015 17:30:54.343 +0.0 (1. Device: Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM1))
```

How could emulate this configuration in a *nix like os  (IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_QUEUE_SIZE, IOCTL_SERIAL_PURGE, IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW and IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at PERL's Device::SerialPort. It does all of this and plenty of good doco to "copy" the windows setup. Latest version has purge_tx, purge_rx. Once initialised, then set baudrate, stopbits, parity, databits